# printing blog posts made by a specific author with foreach and mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, foreach

I want to print something like this

```
blog.author.username.admin.forEach( function(blog) { 
//print posts
});
```

What i want is to print all the posts that have the author with the username admin
but i don't know how

Comment: `db.blog.find({ "author.username": "admin" }).forEach(printjson)`

Comment: I get an error saying: #<Object> is not a function

Comment: Where did you run that command from? It's a mongo shell command by the way so you need to run it from shell and assumes you have a collection with the name `blog` that has a document with the key `author` which holds a subdocument with a `username` property. The comment is just an attempt to drive you closer to the solution, of course you need to give us more details to get a specific answer.

Comment: I want to run that command in a ejs file so it will print all the posts that happen to have been written by the same author in this case admin. (If you need more code tell me. I just don't know what part of it to post)

Comment: Your question is missing salient details like what MongoDB driver you are using (native Node.js driver or Mongoose library), your models (schema definition if using Mongoose or a sample document from the collection) etc Without that I'm afraid the question can be closed as too broad or other close reasons.